# Azure Sprint Backlog error when updating fields

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I get the following error when updating work item fields: e.gettime is not a function. I remember I upgraded the interface a month ago.

I tried to update a work item field and the error popped. That didn't happen before the upgrade.

Comment: Do you have Organisation level permissions to edit the work item templates?